# rbind(x, y) vs. rbind(y, x)

Tags: r, date, rbind

What differences are there between rbind(x, y) and rbind(y, x)?

Why I ask:
Out of desperation I tried both and noticed one worked. Where rbind(x, y) gave me `Error: charToDate string is not in an unambiguous format`, rbind(y, x) did not.

Note I cannot provide a reproducible example as I do not know what caused this discrepancy.

Comment: `x` contains a column with date formatting. `rbind` is trying to convert the column with the same index in `y` from character to date. If you do the inverse, date to character conversion is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all the order of the rows would be different. `rbind` combines the values in the order that they appear in the parameter list.

But the cause of the error is probably more likely to so with S3 method dispatch. Functions in R can behave differently based on the `class()` of the first parameter to that function. If you run `methods(rbind)` you can see the different methods. In base R without other package loaded, these is a special `rbind.data.frame` method. So perhaps in your case just one of `x` or `y` is a data.frame. If you have other packages loaded, you may have additional special versions of `rbind` loaded.

Comment: I have only the `rbind.data.frame` method. Also both x and y are dataframes.

Comment: What are the `class()`es of the columns in your data.frames? Do the column types match up?

Comment: But `rbind()` shouldn't attempt any coercion if everything is character. Verify that's really the case with `str(x)` or `sapply(x, class)` for both data.frames.

Comment: Indeed.. I missed a date column when I thought I converted all date columns to character.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplemental answer to the question's title, I thought it might be useful to run the following benchmark, which gave opposite results to those I expected.

```r
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100000), y = rnorm(100000))
y <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(rbind(x, y), rbind(y, x))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>  rbind(x, y) 4.077496 4.894125 7.351411 5.252737 7.218941 27.39923   100   a
#>  rbind(y, x) 3.385937 3.728124 6.426094 3.980144 5.643514 29.56971   100   a
```

Comment: Now that's interesting!